# Android - How do you save a .JSON to a device?

Tags: android, json

I have created an application. Which gets a .JSON file from a server and reads it.

What I would like to do is to save it onto the device as a .JSON file before it actually does any reading. The reason why I would like to do this, is so you dont need to have an internet connection every time a client uses my application.

Here is an example of the JSON

```
{
"CARS LIST":
    {
    "Car":
        {
        "Make":"BMW",
        "Model":"M3",
        "Engine":"4.0",
        "Desc":"M Power!",
        },

    "Car":
        {
        "Make":"Mercedes",
        "Model":"SLS",
        "Engine":"6.2",
        "Desc":"AMG!",
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You use a database to do that, and in android we use Sqlite.

Comment: @Jonas452 actually it's perfectly okay to save json to a text file, for example if the data doesn't need to be updated

Comment: @Deacoy Is it safe to do this? I think it's better use Sqlite.

Comment: @Jonas452 Thank you I will have a look into sqlite.

Comment: @Deacoy Ah the only problem I have with that... Is that the list can be updated monthly.

Comment: If you don't need to work with data (only read that) and you need to update it only every month it will be a lot more easy to use a file instead of SQLite. Since you can just download the new JSON file from database and save it in the device. No need to write useless code to read and write data in the database. Just parse the file when needed

Comment: thank you @Marco Acierno for clarifying this

Comment: @MarcoAcierno Thanks, I might of misunderstood you, but are saying I cannot get the application to read/get the file again as a .json? The process I would like to do is... Get file from server -> Save file on device -> Then allow the client to turnoff their internet. -> read the json from the device -> put the json into an arraylist with a customobject. -> then let my application do its thing.

Comment: No, I'm saying that you can everything you want with the .json file read it everytime you want. So yes, you can read the json and save all in a arraylist. My comment was about SQLite vs JSON File

Comment: Thank you I have found away of doing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I done it.

1. Get the inputstream
2. Using inputstream.read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int length) store the data as a byte[].
3. Put the byte[] into a char[].
4. Save onto device

Answer (score 1):

You can save this response as a text file with timestamp in filename.
This will tell you upfront when was data updated last time.

Comment: Anyway Java has lastModified and lastModifiedTime not sure if they work in Android but could be a try.

Comment: No need for timestamp in the filename unless he wants to keep old files. The file properties can tell him when the file was last written to (`lastModified()`).